# Conditional on binomial question

Tags: binomial-distribution

Here goes the question from textbook:

A small restaurant seats 20 diners, and is full every night. The chef knows from previous experience that 40% of the diners order steaks, so she always has 12 in her fridge at the beginning of the evening. If a customer orders steak, what is the probability that he/she will receive one?

Apparently, the solution in here https://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120626203618AAsWm24 talks about correction factor. What is the correction factor? and where may I apply it in this context? Thanks in advance for any suggestion related to the theory of this question.

Comment: The question seems slightly ambiguous.  For example, if the customer in question orders *first* then the probability of getting a steak is 1. If she orders *last* then there's a 3.5% chance she gets no steak. The answers you link to presuppose that orders are made simultaneously and that steaks are then randomised over customers who order them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I'd actually call it a 'correction factor' -- it's just using the right constant of summation(/integration) so that the truncated distribution has the correct pmf (/pdf).

A [truncated distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution#Definition) "cuts off" some of the distribution. So for the new, truncated random variable to have a distribution that integrates to 1, you need to divide by the proportion of the original distribution that lies within the bounds.

Since we have a binomial which we know is at least 1, the pmf for the truncated variable is the original density divided by ${1-F(0)}$ (since the new variable is on $1, 2, \ldots n$).